# Why the interpreter doesn‘t report an error?

Tags: python, class, scopes

```
class A:
    name = 10  # this is a class variable

    def fun(self):
        print('this is a function')
        return name  # this is the return value, but same 'name'

name = A()
name.fun()
print(name.fun())
```

```
# operation result
this is a function
this is a function
<__main__.A object at 0x000001D95A894508>
```

It can run successfully, but it does not conform to grammatical logic, why does it(the 'name') not report an error?

Comment: Just FYI, Python uses an *interpreter*, not a *compiler*.

Comment: Are you wondering why you can use the variable name both globally and within the class and the interpreter can differentiate the two instances?  If so, [this may be useful](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)

Comment: You have two variables called "name", one in the class namespace, one in the scripts global namespace. So no clash. If you did try to use `name` twice in the same namespace, python would happily overwrite one with the other. Its a dynamic language.

Comment: It's the global name you used here `name = A()`. Change that to say `foo = A()` and it will complain about `return name`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - I didn't notice that! `return name` is a bug. It only happens to "work" because there is a `name` in the global namespece.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fun` function is valid due to the fact that it references the variable `name` from the global scope (if you name the object of class `A` you've initialized with another name, your code will break).

For example - this code **won't** work:

```
class A:
    name = 10  # this is a class variable

    def fun(self):
        print('this is a function')
        return name  # this is the return value, but same 'name'

object_a = A()
object_a.fun()
```

In your global scope, `name` is defined as an object of class `A` so running `name.fun()` will execute the function `fun` of this object.

If you want to access the *local* variable `name` defined in the class, you can try to run this:

```
name = A()
print(name.name) # output: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug that is masked by the fact that you use `name` in the global namespace. When you use a variable in a method, python checks the method namespace and then falls back to the global namespace. `return name` doesn't see a local `name` but by luck (bad luck), there is a `name` in the global namespace and that is what is returned. If you used that return value later, you'd find it has an instance of A in it.

Instead, use the `self.name` reference. Python will find `self` in the method namespace and seeing that it is an object instance namespace will first check the object namespace and then fall back to the class namespace.

```
class A:
    name = 10  # this is a class variable

    def fun(self):
        print('this is a function')
        return self.name  # this is the return value, but same 'name'

foo = A()
name = foo.fun() 
# three references to the same object
print(name, A.name, foo.name)
```